# Understanding a vector class implementation for vector operations

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm trying to learn a bit about c++ classes and decided to follow the tutorial [here](http://rodrigosavage.blogspot.de/2010/07/simply-vector-math-and-c-vector-class.html) about implementing vector math in c++.  For the most part its very well commented, but there is a line of code here that I'm not following, and when I do my own implementation, my IDE (Xcode) is complaining about it.  After going through the setup of the header file, the author shows us the constructor for this vector class:

```
CVector::CVector (float xi,float yi,float zi){ // Constructor
    x=xi;
    y=yi;
    z=zi;
    w=1.0f; // normalize the vector
}
```

First of all: why is 'w' not being passed to the constructor?  My ide is complaining about the "use of undeclared identifier 'w' "

Second: Does anyone know what he means by normalize the vector?  I'm assuming, because of the notation, that he is specifying the floating point precision for all the other values (i.e. x, y, and z will have 1 decimal place).  Is that right?  If i wanted more precision, would i set w=1.000f; ?

Comment: Float has ~6 decimal points of precision on most platforms, whether you use them or not. It's a fixed storage size.

Comment: Does the IDE or the real compiler complain? Note that the author apparently teaches flawed code; you should use an initialisation list, not assignments.

Comment: @ItsAnApe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector Your assumption is very far from that.

Comment: `w` is declared as a variable in the header, which you should be including in your implementation. `CVector` actually represents a quaternion in the tutorial you have. Since the quaterion represents a point in 3-space, you should only have to enter the first three coordinates. `w` will be modified by the vector operations you define later.

Comment: @LogicStuff. I think the correct link is actually https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Unit_quaternion

Comment: @Mad Physicist nah, it's not quaternion. quaternions have completely different sematntics, also  w=1  as constant will be totally useless in that case (w related to  angle of rotation). It's a canonical, (that is used everywhere, even in OpenGl, IrisGL, DirecX, Vulcan APIs) representation of  vector in 3D space. w allows to differ between points and (radius-vectors) and directions (vectors themselves)

Comment: You may find https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates helpful.

Answer (score 2):

w is defined  there, in header file.  What author doesn't explain, assuming that everyone knows it , tha you need to create header file  - declaration part of code, and implementation file, which  would contain directive #include with name of that header file.

```
#ifndef _CVECTOR_ // Check if C Vector is defined 
#define _CVECTOR_ // the next time CVector will be define
#define ZEROVECTOR CVector()
class  CVector    
{       // Private 
 float x,y,z,w; // Order list of 4 elements |x|y|z|w|
```

Why w needed there and why it initialized with 1? This is not about C++, it's about vector math, linear algebra.

that's not really a normalization of vector.. 4th component used in 3d operation  to determine if vector is direction or position(so called radius vector). IF w=1, then it is position, offset vector in transform matrix will affect it. If w=0, transform matrix can only rotate the vector. If w wouldn't not be  0 or 1, then it  is something equal to uniform scale of space, but it rarely used that way.

Normalization of vector is making its norm to be equal to 1, while preserving direction. But for 4-component 3d vector norm would normalize only 3 first components, leaving w = 1 or 0.

That tutorial uses very primitive and  old version of C++, it looks like it based on  book I have, which had that class written in C++ of 90s version.
Author took that from real use case without explanation.. Such tutorial is as twice as bad. As that is the only constructor of class, that class represents a point in 3D space, not a vector.

C++ can't be learned by example and rote, it's not a scripting language, you should learn theory and syntax, step by step, then you wouldn't have such questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the variables x, y, z, w are should be created in the private section of your CVector class definition, but if the tutorial teaches you like that, please follow another tutorial, the reason is that this code is not teaching you correct c++.

I assume that your class definition, on the header, looks like this:

```
class CVector {
public:
    CVector(float xi, float yi, float zi);
private:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float w;
}
```

and your implementation should be something like this:

```
CVector::CVector(float xi, float yi, float zi) 
: x(xi), y(yi), z(zi), w(1.0f) {
}
```

This Style of initialization is faster than the one you used, more complete explanation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

The reason that w is initialized with 1.0f is beyond me, as it looks like it's a constant that your tutorial choosed.

Comment: > The reason that w is initialized with 1.0f is beyond me < Author took that from real use case without explanation.. Such tutorial is as twice as bad. As that is the only constructor of class, that class represents a point in 3D space , not a vector.

Comment: It is not "faster", it's more *correct* and more *consistent* with use cases where it really does matter.

Comment: just did a dummy test to try and see if it was not faster than calling constructors, and well, it was a bit faster.

Comment: Given the comment, `w` is probably a scale value - this is quite common in graphics vectors to simplify arithmetic operations.  But it's not something we can say for certainty without more context.